# Быстродействие и оптимизация таблицы

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Недавно видел одну очень интересную статью, на одном знаменитом русскоязычном сообществе, где было очень хорошо описано, как можно повысить fps при скролинге таблицы, заполненной ресурсоемкими данными. Для себя, подчеркнул от туда такие вещи как:

1. Расчет высоты ячейки, если он необходим, выполняется вручную, без использования AutoLayout.
2. Биндинг (заполнение) данных в ячейки, должно происходить в методе `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.
3. Нужно избегать смешивания (blending) цветов в ячейках, и стараться выносить ресурсоемкие вычисления в фон.

Теперь хочу знать, что можно (нужно) ещё делать, для оптимизации таблицы?

Comment: Вот та самая ссылку, о которой я говорю в вопросе, считаю очень полезной и нужной (http://habrahabr.ru/post/264817/)

Comment: а не вопрос-опросник ли это :)

Comment: Я так понял, что такие вопросы запрещены, переформулировал вопрос, теперь он выглядит не как опросник)

Comment: На вопрос все еще нельзя дать однозначный ответ.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko я понимаю, что для каждого случаю, необходимо оптимизировать таблицу, исходя из данной ситуации, НО, выше в вопросе я перечислил 3 основных правила, которые я использую, когда уже более ли менее тяжелая таблица возникает, хочется услышать еще что можно делать для любой таблицы, что бы повысить fps.

Comment: и если 10 человек ответят и приведут разные варианты оптимизации, то какой ответ вы примете как правильный?

Comment: кстати, в самой статье в комментариях предлагается несколько оптимизаций.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Предлагается, да только там постоянные споры идут, и обсуждения того что написано в статье, да и больше ничего толком. Так что вопрос остается открытым)))